# NSInvalidArgumentFormatException caused by unrecognized selector was sent to sender : while trying to print tag of a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `ScrollView` which has many blocks of data. Each block has a `UILabel`. I'm creating each of this block inside a for loop :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){

        UILabel *claim = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,135, self.view.bounds.size.width, 30)];
        claim.text = @"claim";
        [claim setTag:i];
        NSLog(@"%ld",claim.tag);
        claim.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(20.0)];
        [claim setTextColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

        //create a tab recogniser for claim text
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(claimClicked:)];
        [claim setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [claim addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [scrollView addSubView :claim];
}
[self.view addSubView : scrollView];
```

The selector for the claim label is  :

```
- (IBAction)claimClicked:(UILabel *)sender{
    NSInteger the_tag = ((UIView*)sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"%ld",the_tag);
}
```

Basically Im just printing the tag on clicking the label. But I get an exception saying :

`NSInvalidArgumentFormatException caused by unrecognized selector was sent to sender` on the NSlog line.

Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the sender here is UITapGestureRecognizer.

Using the code instead:

```
- (IBAction)claimClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.view.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cann't do this definition `- (IBAction)claimClicked:(UILabel *)sender`. Because according to this line `UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(claimClicked:)];`, your sender is `UITapGestureRecognizer.`

Instead try this..

```
- (IBAction)claimClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   if([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
      NSLog(@"Label tag %d",sender.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as required.